# Android Execution failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run my app in Android Studio, this error appears:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

I have tried a lot of solutions but cannot solve the problem.

This is the code for **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and this **build.gradle** is for the library I use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

Comment: By gridle you mean gradle right

Answer (score 0):

The main error seems to be

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

Can you check that you can run java itself successfully? If not, try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dependencies at the build.gradle (the one inside the directory 'app/src', NOT the one inside gradle) to:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' 
}
```

This should solve the problem.